# Need a function!

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone please give me an example of a real-valued smooth function $f$ on the open unit-disk $\mathbb{D}$ such that

$$ 
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  \geq 0 , \text{  if $x\geq0 , y\geq0$} \\                           
                          <0  , \text{  otherwise} .                            \end{cases}  $$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=-g^2(-x)-g^2(-y)$ where 
$$ g(t)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/t}&\text{if }t>0\\0&\text{if }t\le 0\end{cases}$$